# Metadata Fails for Blog Post Like Buttons

Tags: metadata, facebook-like, blogs, meta-tags, blogger

I'm integrating a Like button in the individual blog posts on my company's website ( www.atlas-games.com , blog by CLASSIC Blogger at http://blog.atlas-games.com ... can't use a widget). Unfortunately the metadata isn't passing through, so in Facebook it looks like:

Michelle Nephew likes a link.
Atlas Games: Charting New Realms of Imagination <--website's name, not post title

The item links work correctly on "link" and "Atlas Games ..." directing to the individual post, but it's using generic text rather than the individual post's title, the site name I specified for Facebook, and the image.

Object Debugger comes up with Inferred Property errors for URL, Title, and Image, though I specify them in the header of my page. For some reason Facebook just isn't finding the metadata, seems like. See the report here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.atlas-games.com%2F

I'm having trouble posting my code here ... View Source, though, and you'll see the Meta Property tags in the header and the iframe in the post's footer code (commented out right now).

This is the third time over the course of several months that I've spent hours trying to get this to work, with no luck, so it's not a temporary issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the structure of the HTML might be the issue as it could be stopping Facebook finding the Open Graph tags.

Fixing these validation errors might allow the tags to be parsed:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.atlas-games.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Also there are some template variables in the OG tags which aren't being replaced with values:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<$BlogItemTitle$>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my blog! And I can't even insert html for the facebook like button directly from facebook developers, into my blog, my blogger blog tells me that the html is erred. I think it has something to do with blogger being a google blog and google now having google+. I noticed all my problems began when google+ came out, I think google is possibly screwing up the facebook like buttons on google sites, to gain monopoly through "share on google+" .